# Regular expression to parse img tag

Tags: php, regex

I have a little problem with my regular expression, that I use in PHP. My code identify all  tags of my content and add a link in this image. My code is working when I use dinamycally, without any defined image. When I try with a imapge path, the code does not work. How can I solve this problem?

```
Working code:
$content = preg_replace('/(<img .*?src="(.+?)".*?>)/','<a class="nyromodal foto" href="'.$imagem_wordpress.'">\1</a>', $content);


Problem code:
$content = preg_replace('/(<img .*?src="http://mysite.com/files/2010/04/bac-gallery-site-matters-saline-project1.jpg".*?>)/','<a class="nyromodal foto" href="'.$imagem_wordpress.'">\1</a>', $content);
```

Comment: Watch out for the "." in the filename of the URL.  You need to escape that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<img .*?src="http:\/\/mysite.com\/files\/2010\/04\/bac-gallery-site-matters-saline-project1\.jpg".*?>)/','<a class="nyromodal foto" href="'.$imagem_wordpress.'">\1</a>', $content);
```

You forgot to escape your forward slashes. (And as pointed out by others, it should be "http" and not "ttp"

Comment: You forgot to escape the first `.` in the url. Although the regex still matches, it'll also match `mysitescom/files/...`, which probably isn't what you want

Comment: Choosing a delimiter other than '/' will result in a less cluttered regex: `#(<img .*?src="http://mysite.com/files/2010/04/bac-gallery-site-matters-saline-project1\.jpg".*?>)#`

Answer (score 0):

Should that be `src="http` in the problem code instead of `src="ttp`?